# getContentResolver.openInputStream returns an empty stream

Tags: android, kotlin

I am sharing an audio file(opus file) from WhatsApp to my app.
When I am trying to read the file using

```
val uri: Uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)
val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
val byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)
```

I am getting an empty `ByteArray`

I've tried using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` like this:

```
val uri: Uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)
val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
```

But `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` only returns `null`.

I also tried querying the content resolver for this `uri`, but all I get is the file name and the file size.

The `uri` value is `"content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/133401"`

However, when I am trying to share an image from WhatsApp to my App, and use the same code as above, everything works well and I get the desired `byteArray`.

I would love to have some help here

Thanks!

Comment: tried to `read()` few first bytes from that `InputStream`?

Comment: it returns `-1`

Comment: and whats on the logcat after calling:  `Cursor c = contentResolver.query(uri,null,null,null,null); DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c)`

Comment: It says that the size of the file is 0. It's wierd I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: yep, good luck / hunting